# How to get following values

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

I am doing projec using mongodb with ODM tool. so here I try to use find query. this is my code

```
$dm    = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
$user = $dm->getRepository('Application\Document\User')->findOneBy(array('username' => 'admin'));
```

so now $user variable contain some values related to find query. so when I use `var_dump($user)` it show following result

> object(Application\Document\User)#253 (4) { ["id":"Application\Document\User":private]=> string(24) "5103d0aca00b2a3205000001" ["username":"Application\Document\User":private]=> string(5) "admin" ["email":"Application\Document\User":private]=> string(15) "admin@xmail.com" ["password":"Application\Document\User":private]=> string(3) "abc" }

so please tell me how to get `username` value from the `$user` object`.

Comment: `$user->getUsername()` should get your value, you will need to define a getter/setter for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a protected `username` member in your `User` entity. Once you have that you should add your getters and setters for that member and use them to fetch given value.

```
$user->getUsername();
```

You could also optionally run `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` to let Doctrine generate getters and setter functions for all of your entities.